# User Defined Types not storing data within the module

Tags: vb6

I am not sure if i am doing anything wrong, i have a UDT which i populate with data in one procedure but i cannot retrieve that data in the next procedure.

```
Private Type APP
    name As String
    version As String
End Type

Private Sub Form_load()
    Call Process1
    Call Process2
End Sub

Private Sub Process1
    Dim data As APP

    data.name = "MyApp"
    data.version = "1"
End Sub

Private Sub Process2
    Dim data As APP

    Debug.Print "Name: "; data.name
    Debug.Print "Version: "; data.version
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim` creates a *local* variable - it exists in that procedure only (`Process1`).  Even if you have a form/module level variable, you are creating *another* local one in `Process2`.  Read up on `Variable Scope`

Comment: Ahh.. i had to create a variable with that data type within the module.